# Does the distribution of $|f|$ coincides with that of $|g|$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g$ be two (Lebesgue) measurable function on $[0,1]$.
Assume that
$$\int \frac{\alpha |f(m)|}{1+\alpha |f(m)|}dm =\int \frac{\alpha |g(m)|}{1+\alpha|g(m)|}dm $$
for any $\alpha \ge 0$.
Does the distribution of $|f|$ coincide with that of $|g|$?

Comment: Any thoughts?$\vphantom{hi}$

Comment: @nejimban Say, for $f=\chi_{(0,1)}$, if $\|g\|_\infty \le 1$, then $f=|g|$.